# After updating 12.04 login time has shooted up drastically?

Tags: 12.04, login, snmp

I updated ubuntu 12.04 yesterday. In that update firefox, thunderbird, kernel and snmp packages were updated. After this my login time has increased from 5-10sec to 30-45sec. 
I surely think it is the snmp packages that are causing trouble. How do i fix those packages to get back my login time...?

Comment: Have you rebooted more than once since the updates? Sometimes the first login time can be significantly greater than later logins.

Comment: yes quite a lot of times...

Answer (score 2):

You should first get some data, using bootchart ( http://www.freetechie.com/blog/visually-seeing-your-boot-speed-with-bootchart-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/ ). So you can see what is taking time.

Then, once you have a rough idea, you can either :
- disable service that are useless for you 
- try to see what take time

I would recommend to check before removing anything, of course. Removing snmp is harmless removing something like dkms may let you without working X if you use nvidia driver.

Do not act in hurry :)